# Create dynamic HTML page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, popup

I am using asp.net 2.0 and C#.

I have a teacher-student concept, in which I want that whenever a student login he/she will get a pop up made by his/her teacher. 
My issue is this I want to give an interface to teacher that he can design his own html page and assign is to all student or a particular student[i.e. he can made different html pop up for different student].

How can I design a interface in which teacher can create a html page. or if you have any other idea to do this, please share

Answer (score 0):

Let me brief the question little
if your teacher has to store the message for all/any one student, then you can store it in the databse on the student table itself.

whenever the student loggin he will get the message on his default page.
you can use ajax if the teacher want to share some message for all/any one student, if he/she is logged in then immidietely will popup. for non logged in students on their next loggon.

for popup display you can design templete html. then u can update the template with message before we bring the popup on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via content management system.

There will be a dropdownlist which will have all and individual student options.

And there will be html editor which will have all html desinged and store that in database.

Whenever student logged in it will display the html content from the database.